# In Laravel, which Eloquent methods return data and which return objects?

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent

I'm getting confused with the various functions in Laravel's Eloquent ORM and what they return. I have a Post model for a blog - if I write any of the following then I get back an array of all the posts:

```
$posts = Post::all();
$posts = Post::get();
$posts = Post::with('user')->all();
```

However, if I chain some other methods, it doesn't work. For example this gives an Unhandled Exception error: "Method [all] is not defined on the Query class."

```
$posts = Post::with('user')->order_by('updated_at', 'desc')->all();
```

And if I use the paginate function, I don't get an array of results at all.

```
$posts = Post::with('user')->order_by('updated_at', 'desc')->paginate(5);

// index.blade.php
@foreach ($posts as $post)
    {{ $post->id }}
@endforeach
```

I get the error: "Trying to get property of non-object". Turns out the data is in `$posts->results`, not `$posts`.

This is all very confusing! How do I get my head around this? What do each of these functions return and how do I chain them correctly?

Comment: 14.8k, right? I'm not saying you can't ask this here but reading the code would solve your problem with a much better learning effect for yourself.

Comment: @markus-tharkun Perhaps, but I am new to Laravel and thought someone else might be able to explain it better than me diving into some alien code (which isn't very well documented from what I have seen/heard). And it would be useful for anyone else.

Comment: Also, I don't see how my rep matters, getting 14k in 4 years is nothing, that's like 1 upvote a day on average...

Comment: I honestly think that the documentation is adequate. There's a getting started type guide and then there's the API. http://laravel.com/api/ With these and PHP experience you can learn the framework very quickly.

Comment: @ShawnMcCool This isn't the place for an extended discussion about the docs but I respectfully disagree. I know you are heavily involved in Laravel so it's probably difficult to look at it from the outside but there are key pieces of required/useful information missing from the docs and code. (Despite that I am loving the framework so I will try and do my bit to help remedy that.)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Without going through every single method available the simple answer is to figure out what data type the output is.

```
dd($whatever);
```

If it's an object then find the class that the object is an instance of and understand how that class works.

If it's a query object, you can chain it, if it's an array or null you can't. If it's an instance of a model class then you CAN chain it, but you can only call methods that exist in the model class or in your derivative class.

Here's a brief article that I write about Eloquent and Fluent that may be helpful as well: http://laravel.io/topic/17/what-are-fluent-and-eloquent

Comment: Those not familiar with Laravel helper functions such as `dd()` will enjoy the [helpers documentation](http://four.laravel.com/docs/helpers#miscellaneous).

Answer (score 7):

When I run this:

```
$user = User::where('email','=','test@example.com');
dd($user); # object(Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Builder)

// After: 
dd($user->get()); # object(Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Collection)

// And finally, to get model object:
dd($user->get()->first()); # object(App\User)
```

Answer (score 0):

By peeking into the source code, it's not that badly documented:

https://github.com/laravel/laravel/blob/master/laravel/database/eloquent/query.php#L98

Every method has `@return` on their phpdoc so you immediately know what should they return. I suggest you read the [docs](http://laravel.com/docs/views/pagination) as well.

Comment: Which means, @DisgruntledGoat, even your IDE should tell you exactly what you can do with it and what you can't. I'm guessing you need to update your toolchain too?

Comment: @return, im looking on this. thanks, weird why I found this on a stackoverflow answer